# Интеграция ASP.NET Core и MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Друзья, возможно кто-нибудь интегрировал ASP.NET Core сервер и БД MySQL. Буду рад правильным статьям. Любой информации от вас.

Comment: а какие с этим проблемы? Берете [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) и вперед.

Comment: tym32167, а почему какое-то Pomelo надо брать, а не официальный оракловский пакет? [MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/). Да и вообще EF/EFCore не обязательны.

Comment: @АндрейNOP оно было просто выше в [списке](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/providers/), а так можно хоть что использовать, я потому и спросил, какие у автора проблемы.